# Multiple Rows, wrapped in one object

Tags: java, sql

This is a follow up on my last question, building my dynamic questionnaire.

So I have query that joins all the tables I need to dynamically create the page.

Structure looks as follows(Cant upload picture, not enough rep)

```
Question    QuestionType        Possible answer 
-------------------------------------------
How far     Single Choice       Too Far 
How far     Single Choice       Not too far 
How long    Multiple Choice     Way long
How long    Multiple Choice     Huh?
How long    Multiple Choice     Dumb question
```

The query returns a row for each possible answer, sometimes 2, other times 4. No restriction how many options a single question can have.

In my project i have an XML structure that my application uses to build the page.

```
<rowset>
    <row>
        <questionText>This is a single choice question*</questionText>
        <questionType>Single Choice</questionType>
        <possibleAnswerSet>
            <possibleAnswer>Yes</possibleAnswer>
            <possibleAnswer>No</possibleAnswer>
            <possibleAnswer>Maybe</possibleAnswer>
        </possibleAnswerSet>
    </row>
    <row>
        <questionText>This is a survey question</questionText>
        <questionType>Survey</questionType>
        <possibleAnswerSet>
            <possibleAnswer></possibleAnswer>
        </possibleAnswerSet>
    </row>
    <row>
        <questionText>This is a mutiple choice question*</questionText>
        <questionType>Multiple Choice</questionType>
        <possibleAnswerSet>
            <possibleAnswer>Apples</possibleAnswer>
            <possibleAnswer>Bananas</possibleAnswer>
            <possibleAnswer>Cranberries</possibleAnswer>
            <possibleAnswer>Dragon fruit</possibleAnswer>
        </possibleAnswerSet>
    </row>
</rowset>
```

This piece works perfect, with data hard coded in the XML, my page generates.
So my question is, from resultSet that is returned from my query, i want to wrap all the associated answers in List or some other collection, so that i can populate the XML as described above.

This is how Im currently setting, and It returns an object for each POSSIBLE_ANSWER, not each Question

```
try 
        {
            while (rset.next()) 
            {
                ClientPojo clientObj = new ClientPojo();

                questionOptions = rset.getInt("QUESTION_OPTIONS");
                passPercentage = rset.getInt("CATEGORY_PASS_PERCENTAGE");
                questionText = rset.getString("QUESTION_TEXT");
                questionType = rset.getString("QUESTION_TYPE");
                categoryName = rset.getString("CATEGORY_NAME");
                possibleAnswerText = rset.getString("POSSIBLE_ANSWER_TEXT");
                possibleAnswerCorrect = rset.getString("POSSIBLE_ANSWER_CORRECT");
                questionId = rset.getInt("QUESTION_ID");

                clientObj.setAssessmentAreaId(assessmentAreaId);
                clientObj.setCategoryName(categoryName);
                clientObj.setPassPercentage(passPercentage);
                clientObj.setPossibleAnswerCorrect(possibleAnswerCorrect);
                clientObj.setPossibleAnswerText(possibleAnswerText);
                clientObj.setQuestionOptions(questionOptions);
                clientObj.setQuestionText(questionText);
                clientObj.setQuestionType(questionType);
                clientObj.setQuestionId(questionId);

                questionsList.add(clientObj);
            }
        }
```

Is what i want possible with the query im using, or do i need to change that.

EDIT:
Here's my query:

```
SELECT "CAQ_SCHEMA"."QUESTION".*, "CAQ_SCHEMA"."CATEGORY".*, "CAQ_SCHEMA"."CATEGORY_QUESTION_LINK".*, "CAQ_SCHEMA"."POSSIBLE_ANSWER".* , "CAQ_SCHEMA"."ASSESSMENT_AREA".* 
FROM "CAQ_SCHEMA"."QUESTION" 
    JOIN "CAQ_SCHEMA"."CATEGORY_QUESTION_LINK" 
        ON "CAQ_SCHEMA"."CATEGORY_QUESTION_LINK".QUESTION_ID = "CAQ_SCHEMA"."QUESTION".QUESTION_ID
    JOIN "CAQ_SCHEMA"."POSSIBLE_ANSWER"
        ON "CAQ_SCHEMA"."POSSIBLE_ANSWER".QUESTION_ID = "CAQ_SCHEMA"."QUESTION".QUESTION_ID
    JOIN "CAQ_SCHEMA"."CATEGORY" 
        ON "CAQ_SCHEMA"."CATEGORY".CATEGORY_ID = "CAQ_SCHEMA"."CATEGORY_QUESTION_LINK".CATEGORY_ID
    JOIN "CAQ_SCHEMA"."ASSESSMENT_AREA"
        ON "CAQ_SCHEMA"."ASSESSMENT_AREA".ASSESSMENT_AREA_ID = "CAQ_SCHEMA"."CATEGORY".ASSESSMENT_AREA_ID
    WHERE "CAQ_SCHEMA"."ASSESSMENT_AREA".ASSESSMENT_AREA_ID = '1';
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: Hard to answer if your query is appropriate without knowing your query...

Comment: Fair enough, this query is messy right now, just grabbing all fields, going to refine it later to return only what i need. Edited my question, addedd query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm mistaken, but what about using a map questionId->question and then do something like this?

```
Map<Integer, ClientPojo> questions = new HashMap<Integer, ClientPojo>();

while (rset.next()) 
{
  questionId = rset.getInt("QUESTION_ID");

  ClientPojo clientObj = questions.get(questionId);
  if( clientObj == null ) 
  {
    ClientPojo clientObj = new ClientPojo();

    questionOptions = rset.getInt("QUESTION_OPTIONS");
    passPercentage = rset.getInt("CATEGORY_PASS_PERCENTAGE");
    questionText = rset.getString("QUESTION_TEXT");
    questionType = rset.getString("QUESTION_TYPE");
    categoryName = rset.getString("CATEGORY_NAME");

    clientObj.setAssessmentAreaId(assessmentAreaId);
    clientObj.setCategoryName(categoryName);
    clientObj.setPassPercentage(passPercentage);
    clientObj.setQuestionOptions(questionOptions);
    clientObj.setQuestionText(questionText);
    clientObj.setQuestionType(questionType);
    clientObj.setQuestionId(questionId);

    questionsList.add(clientObj);
  }

  possibleAnswerText = rset.getString("POSSIBLE_ANSWER_TEXT");
  possibleAnswerCorrect = rset.getString("POSSIBLE_ANSWER_CORRECT");

  //I'll leave the Answert object for you
  clientObj.addPossibleAnswer( new Answer(possibleAnswerText, possibleAnswerCorrect ) );
}
```

Joins will naturally result in multiple result sets if there are multiple answers. Thus you either use 2 queries (one for the questions and one for the possible answers) or just ignore the question data whenever you've already created a question and only add the additional answers.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for your suggestions, I managed to get it working by using two queries. Initially I didn't want to go this route, but it ended up to be the quickest solution.